Can a non-uniform quantum machine simulate a non-uniform classical machine with respect to any oracle?
I'm familiar with the result that $\mathbf{BPP} \subseteq \mathbf{BQP}$ by a simulation argument, and I know that this result relativizes, so $\forall O, \mathbf{BPP}^O \subseteq \mathbf{BQP}^O$.
My question is: is this true even when considering polynomial classical advice? Intuitively, it seems like it should be true, but I can't find a source backing this up.
Is there a proof that $\forall O, \mathbf{BPP}_{/\mathrm{poly}}^O \subseteq \mathbf{BQP}_{/\mathrm{poly}}^O$? If not, is it considered to be trivial, or am I missing something?

As far as I can see, adding advice trivially preserves inclusion of classes.
